# jQuery Mobile UI - Panels - Clicking within the panel closes the panel

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, panels

I'm using jQuery Mobile UI and need a bit of help with Panels as seen here.

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/panel/

I have implemented it as an overlay without a problem but the click outside the panel to dismiss has an issue where it also includes about 20% of the panel. So if I click upto 20% in the panel, it closes. This is problematic because I have buttons that don't work when users click them because the panel closes.

Any ideas how I can fiddle with the panel dismissing settings? For now, I've turned of dismissing by clicking outside the panel.

Thanks.

Comment: This isn't normal behaviour so its likely specific to your scenario. Give some example of the code used preferably in a jsfiddle would help people debug the issue for you.

Comment: Are you overriding pnael's width? To be precise, are you increasing pnael's width?